# Get the size on a included model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller I am loading from a table all the `words` those `words` are associated with another table `words has_many related_words`, I can get all the `related_words` but instead I would like to get the number of `related_words`

```
format.json {render json: words, except: [:created_at], include: {related_words: {only: :name}}, status: :ok}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you want the size of related_words of that word.

Comment: yes I want for each word the size of related_words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.size is usually what you want, it will do a .count or .length depending on whether or not the collection is loaded.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/size

If you are looking to put this in the json output, you'd do it like this:

`format.json {render json: words, except: [:created_at], include: {related_words: {only: :name}, methods: related_words_count}, status: :ok}`

In word.rb

```
def related_words_count
  related_words.size
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `words.related_words.count`

for the number of related words.

Comment: it will not work, because words is a collection and related_words is another collection, I need to get for each word the size of related_words

Answer (score 0):

For a particular **word** this will give the size of associated **related_words** size

```
word.related_words.size
```